# Why does the state return to the InitialState when the page is refreshed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox for notifications and if we checked it, I want it to stay that way when the page is refreshed. In my `userProfileSlice.js` file, I send this request to the backend and update the `comms_optin_email` state with the response. I take this value from the `state.userProfile.updateNotificationSettings` state in the `initialState` of the Checkbox and put it. But when I check and refresh the page, the state returns to false. How can I solve this?

NotificationsSettingsPage

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateNotificationSettingsStarted } from '../../../store/userProfileSlice';
import CommunicationPermisson from '../../AuthPages/CommunicationPermissionModal/CommunicationPermisson';
import NiceModal from '@ebay/nice-modal-react';

export default function NotificationSettingsPage() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { auth } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    const { comms_optin_email } = useSelector(
        state => state.userProfile.updateNotificationSettings,
    );
    const [isOffersChecked, setIsOffersChecked] = useState(comms_optin_email);
    const nanoid = auth?.user?.nanoid;

    const handleOffersClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        NiceModal.show(CommunicationPermisson);
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
            updateNotificationSettingsStarted({
                nanoid: nanoid,
                isOffersChecked: isOffersChecked,
            }),
        );
    };

    return (
        <section aria-labelledby="payment-details-heading">
            <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                <div className="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="bg-white py-6 px-4 sm:p-6">
                        <div>
                            <h2
                                id="payment-details-heading"
                                className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900"
                            >
                                {t('notificationSettings.heading')}
                            </h2>
                            <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                {t('notificationSettings.description')}
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:items-baseline">
                            <div className="mt-6 sm:col-span-2">
                                <div className="max-w-xl space-y-4">
                                    <div>
                                        <div className="relative flex items-start">
                                            <div className="flex items-center h-5">
                                                <input
                                                    id="offers"
                                                    name="offers"
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    className="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
                                                    checked={isOffersChecked}
                                                    onChange={() => setIsOffersChecked(!isOffersChecked)}
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                                                <label
                                                    htmlFor="offers"
                                                    className="font-medium text-gray-700"
                                                >
                                                    {t('Offers')}
                                                </label>
                                                <p className="text-gray-500">
                                                    {t('notificationSettings.offerNotificationTextStart')}
                                                    <button
                                                        className="text-indigo-600 underline"
                                                        type="button"
                                                        onClick={handleOffersClick}
                                                    >
                                                        {t(
                                                            'notificationSettings.offerNotificationPopButton',
                                                        )}
                                                    </button>
                                                    {t('notificationSettings.offerNotificationTextEnd')}
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm py-2 px-4 inline-flex justify-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-900"
                        >
                            {t('Save')}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    );
}
```

userProfileSlice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    updateNotificationSettings: {
        error: false,
        success: false,
        fetch: false,
        message: '',
        comms_optin_email: false,
    },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unused-modules
export const userProfileSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'userProfile',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateNotificationSettingsStarted: state => {
            state.updateNotificationSettings = {
                error: false,
                success: false,
                fetch: true,
                message: '',
                comms_optin_email: false,
            };
        },
        updateNotificationSettingsFinished: (state, action) => {
            state.updateNotificationSettings = {
                error: false,
                success: true,
                fetch: false,
                message: '',
                comms_optin_email: action.payload,
            };
        },
        updateNotificationSettingsFailed: (state, action) => {
            state.updateNotificationSettings = {
                error: true,
                success: false,
                fetch: false,
                message: action.payload,
            };
        },
    },
});

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unused-modules
export const {
    updateNotificationSettingsStarted,
    updateNotificationSettingsFinished,
    updateNotificationSettingsFailed,
} = userProfileSlice.actions;

export default userProfileSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: When the page is refreshed? If you’re not loading from the DB or something persistent on the client side (e.g., local storage) when the page is refreshed the JS context is initialized—that’s just how browsers work.

Comment: You might want to try [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)